# Store image EXIF mata data in dictonary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, upload, exif

I want to store EXIF data of image in  `DictRequest`.

How can I do so? Please help me

Below is the code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [temp defaultRepresentation];

StrPath = [StrPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.%@",(int)timeInterval,strImageType];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
NSLog(@"Image width %f Image height %f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

NSData *dataObj = nil;
dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

NSLog(@"Length of data %d",[dataObj length]);
NS    tring* StrFileData = [Base64 encode:dataObj];
NSString* strFileHash = [dataObj md5Test];

//----------------------------------------------------
NSMutableDictionary *DictRequest = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[DictRequest setObject:srtprefSessionId forKey:@"SessionId"];
[DictRequest setObject:StrPath forKey:@"Path"];
[DictRequest setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isTrash] forKey:@"UploadDirectlyToTrashbin"];
[DictRequest setObject:StrFileData forKey:@"FileData"];
[DictRequest setObject:strFileHash forKey:@"FileHash"];
[DictRequest setObject:result forKey:@"DateCreated"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the metadata of the image with `[rep metadata]`. The Dictionary should contain the EXIF data. The EXIF data is not accessable throu an UIImage-object.